# Print out Retry(5) attempts in Rx

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive

I'm learning Rx and I wonder how I could print out the retries to the console, e.g. "Retry #1", "Retry #2", etc. I have seen some people using `.Dump` extension method that I cannot find.

```cs
using System.Reactive.Concurrency;
using System.Reactive.Linq;
using System.Reactive.Threading.Tasks;

var test = new Test(new HttpClient());
var result = await test.GetAsync();
Console.WriteLine($"Result: {result}");

public sealed class Test
{
    private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;

    public Test(HttpClient httpClient)
    {
        _httpClient = httpClient;
    }

    public Task<string> GetAsync()
    {
        return Observable
            .FromAsync(() => _httpClient.GetAsync("http://www.mocky.io/v2/5e307edf3200005d00858b49"))
            .SubscribeOn(TaskPoolScheduler.Default)
            .Retry(5)
            .Timeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5))
            .Do(x => Console.WriteLine($"Is message successful? {x.IsSuccessStatusCode}"))
            .SelectMany(async x =>
            {
                var response = await x.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                return response;
            })
            .Catch<string, TimeoutException>(_ => Observable.Return("Timeout"))
            .Catch<string, Exception>(ex => Observable.Return(ex.Message))
            .ToTask();
    }
}
```

Comment: I get that the objective is to learn Rx but _just for the records_: I'd prefer Polly for this.

Comment: `.Dump()` comes from [LINQPad](https://www.linqpad.net/). I do most of my coding in LP now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a basic example of writing out retries:

```
Observable
    .Defer<int>(() =>
    {
        int counter = 0;
        return
            Observable
                .Defer<int>(() =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(counter++ > 0 ? $"Retry #{counter - 1}" : "First");
                    return Notification.CreateOnError<int>(new Exception()).ToObservable();
                })
                .Retry(5);
    })
    .Subscribe(
        x => Console.WriteLine(x),
        e => Console.WriteLine(e.Message));
```

This outputs:

```
First
Retry #1
Retry #2
Retry #3
Retry #4
Exception of type 'System.Exception' was thrown.
```

The observable you're retrying should be wrapped in a `Observable.Defer` to prevent the potential for repeated values. And, whenever I use "external" state in an observable I also wrap it in a `Observable.Defer`.